# Cannot connect to WSL using Tramp (all localhost)

Tags: tramp, ssh, wsl

this is my `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`

```
Host wsl
 User daniele
 Port 2222
 HostName localhost
```

If I open a cmd and run `ssh wsl` everything works like a charm.

But when I try:

```
C-x C-f /ssh[x]:daniele@localhost#2222:
```

I get in return:

```
ssh -l daniele -p 2222 -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none                         localhost && exit || exit
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
getsockname failed: Not a socket
packet_write_poll: Connection to UNKNOWN port -1: Permission denied
```

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try `C-x C-f /plink@localhost#2222:` ?

Comment: It works as expected, but I wonder why Tramp cannot invoke ssh correctly.

Comment: It isn't Tramp, I believe. People have tried it already in the past, and it failed for reasons of Microsofts ssh implementation. I cannot test anything on MS Windows, but if somebody has a working recipe, I'm willing to add it to Tramp. (I'm the Tramp maintainer)